# How to make Exit confirmation yes or no on Control Button using C# Window Form

Tags: c#

I have a one issue in my window application, there are two form :login and main.

I have created Exit Button on both form  and also coded of Exit Confirmation.

It works fine when we Press Exit Button message No on form 1.    But We login to on form to

another form  and second form Exit Button message button press No , and then back to return

form one and then click exit btton No ::::::it will display two times message PopUp of confirmation...............

**Code**

```
private void Btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question); 
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes) 
    { 
       Application.ExitThread(); 
    } else 
    { } 
}
```

Plz there is any solution in c#............

Comment: private void Btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.ExitThread();
            }

            else
            {

            
            }
        }

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: private void Btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.ExitThread();
            }

            else
            {

            
            }
        }

Comment: Is the other form just hidden upon Exit?

Comment: Yes.................When Back  form2 to form 1 :  Form1 show and Form 2 will hide

Comment: please try to explain a bit more. Question is not clear.....

Answer (score 2):

Just code this.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case consider `LoginForm` and `MainForm` , Once you logged in you try to hide the `LoginForm` and show `MainForm`. Problem is when you try to close `MainForm` it will invoke the respective `FormCloseEvent` and once you chose to close, it automatically invoke parent form that is hiding in background, so it invokes `LoginForm's` `FormCloseEvent`. This is the reason for two time Popups.

To resolve this you need to trigger an event i.e whenever Child form is closed you need to raise a flag, so in your parent's `FormCloseEvent` you need to check for flag, if flag is true you no need to show the pop up.

```
    private bool isMainFormClosed = false;

    private void showMainForm()
    {
        // Hide the loginform UI.
        this.Hide();

        var mainForm = new MainForm();

        // Creating close event for mainform, whenever close icon is clicked it will close the login form which is hiding in background.
        mainForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(mainFormClosed);

        // Show the mainform UI
        mainForm.Show();
    }

    private void mainFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.isMainFormClosed = true;

        this.Close();
    }

    private void loginFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {   
        if(!this.isMainFormClosed)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the application",AppConstants.APPLICATION_NAME,
                                                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if(dialogResult == DialogResult.No) 
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DialogResult` is returned by `dialogs` after dismissal.
 It indicates which button was clicked on the dialog by the user.

### Code

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string message = "Do you want to exit?";
    const string caption = "EXIT";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close this application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```